# QGIS Save to File naming probelm

Tags: qgis

In Noosa 3.6.3 when I run a tool (for example: Regular Points) I save the output to file and choose SHP files. But the name I choose do not appear in the table of content. Instead, when the tool finish running, it adds a generic name of "Regular Points" and not the name I picked for the SHP file.
Is there a way to force QGIS tools to add the output file actual name and not the name of the tool like its doing now? See snapshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming that you're defining the name and file location after clicking save to file? [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX4N9.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX4N9.png) Chris

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you set this behavior in the general processing option (Setting menu > option > Processing tab > General) by ticking/unticking the "Use filename as layer name" box

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thank you J R!